# From what height will a cat take fall damage?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

From what height will a cat take fall damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cats will not take fall damage, although they will still try to avoid falling off cliffs. I’m not sure about your iron golem situation, but I do believe that it is impossible to make a java-style iron farm with villagers.

Comment: Note: "Cliffs" means any drop of 4 or more tiles high.

Comment: You can make an iron farm on Bedrock with that, I solved my problem, they kept spawning behind a step so I placed dirt blocks so that they wouldnt spawn there (what's is hilarious is that sometimes a cat will spawn in the dirt blocks i have there but it'll suffocate and die)